# Excel 2013 with Power Query Add-in, VBA does not seem to support query syntax

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry my second post on the same subject. I have some code written in VBA using Excel 2016 that I need to migrate to support at least Excel 2013.

I posted to ask if anyone has ideas on how to migrate the code - whilst waiting for a response on that, I tried to install Power Query add-in, which was done successfully, but the VBA code is still throwing a 438 run-time error.

The Power Query add-in appears enabled by default - I check in File -> Options -> COM Add-ins, and power query is checked.

The code I'm running is this:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count
    If ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Item(i).Name = itemToMatch Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Item(i).Delete
    End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=itemToMatch, Formula:=Formula

End Sub
```

It throws an error at ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count, which should be a valid format?

Thank you in advance again.

Comment: It looks like [`Queries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.queries) was added to the object model in 2016.

Comment: So power query add-in does not support Queries object model? I'm really new to the SQL side of things for Excel and am finding this so frustrating.

Comment: The add-in is separate from the actual Excel object model. There may be an alternative but I'm not sure (can't test as I have a later version of Excel).

Comment: You may be able to access your Queries through the `Workbook.Connections` collection.  [This might give you some clues](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/10/22/refresh-power-query-with-vba/)